# KeyPress/EditorAction event handler getting called multiple times

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, event-handling

I've combined both `Keypress` and `EditorAction` event handlers of EditText control into a single method called **InputField_KeyPressEditorAction**. When I input some text and press Enter the following code executes multiple times (2, 3 or more):

```
private void InputField_KeyPressEditorAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ke = e as View.KeyEventArgs;
        var eae = e as TextView.EditorActionEventArgs;

        if (ke != null)
        {
            ke.Handled = false;
        }

        if (eae != null)
        {
            eae.Handled = false;
        }

        if (ke != null && (ke.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down || ke.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Up) &&
            (ke.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter || ke.KeyCode == Keycode.Unknown) ||
            eae != null && eae.ActionId == ImeAction.Done)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_inputField.Text)) return;
            _inputField.Text = Regex.Replace(_inputField.Text, @"\t|\n|\r", string.Empty);


            if (_notificationArea.Text.Contains(_scanEan))
            {
                // Following code executes twice....
            }

            if (ke != null)
            {
                ke.Handled = true;
            }

            if (eae != null)
            {
                eae.Handled = true;
            }

            var imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(InputMethodService);
            imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(CurrentFocus.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        }
    }
```

The part where I assign event handler to the control:

```
        _inputField = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextScan);
        _inputField.KeyPress += InputField_KeyPressEditorAction;
        _inputField.EditorAction += InputField_KeyPressEditorAction;
```

What's the reason for this strange behaviour? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the events are not hooked up multiple times? If not sure you can unhook then (`-=`) before hooking them up.

Comment: No, they're attached only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EditText.EditorAction` (`TextView.IOnEditorActionListener`) is going to be called for each key up, down, longpress, and multiplekey along with 10 different `ImeAction` based actions.

You should separate the keypress and editaction event handlers into separate functions.

Comment: ok I'll separate the event handlers and give feedback if it worked

Comment: The actual problem was, the code executed once for KeyEventActions.Down and once for KeyEventActions.Up after pressing Enter. Commenting out the **Up** part did the job.